# Working code for getting frame from video

Tags: android, android-ndk

Here that I have - 
I need to get a frame from the specific time in the video.
my application should work on all SDK starting from 1.6 (so MediaMetadataRetriever is
not an option for me)

As far as I understand the only way is to use ffmpeg with everything related to it, is that right?

I am wondering, if it is a quite popular operation, is there any working solution for it? I mean just some
code that I can simply grab and use? Maybe some open source application?

Thanks in advance